# Xcode warnings not showing

Tags: xcode, warnings

I enabled all warnings/issues in Xcode, but they aren't shown anymore (it worked 2 days ago, when I had 950 warnings).
In the project settings I checked "Show all issues" and in the build settings I enabled every even remotely relevant warning.
That happens in every project I open.
I even trashed the preferences.

I do however get errors.

Any ideas?

Xcode 9.3 on HighSierra

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the scheme -> build -> check Analyse and Test

[image]